# C++ perfect shuffle logical error, I cant seem to fix it?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

The code is supposed to  performs perfect shuffle on an array of integers.A perfect
shuffle is a sequence obtained by interleaving its first half with the second half, always
moving the middle card to the front. For example, the perfect shuffle of
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} is {6,1,7,2,8,3,9,4,10,5}.The problem withh my code is that it doesnt display the desired output instead it shows sum random numbers.Thank you in advance

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userArray[25], a[20], b[20];
    int i, sizeofarray, half, j, m;

    A: cout << "Enter SIZE of even numbers: ";
    cin >> sizeofarray;
    if (sizeofarray % 2 != 0)
    {
        cout << "Wrong Input!!,you should enter an even size (2,4,...)";
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        goto A;
    }
    cout << "Enter  numbers:  \n";
    for (i = 0; i < sizeofarray; i++)
    {
        cin >> userArray[i];
    }

    // for(i=0;i<sizeofarray;i++)
    //{

    half = sizeofarray / 2;
    cout << "The perfect shuffle is: \n";
    for (j = 0; j <= half; j++)
    {
        a[j] = userArray[j];
        cout << a[j];
    }
    for (m = half; m <= sizeofarray; m++)
    {
        b[m] = userArray[m];
        cout << b[m];
    }

//}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used to arrays to get the first half and second half

Comment: `m<=sizeofarray` is wrong. And you print `userArray[half]` twice. And you probably want to print some spaces between numbers, to make it clear which number is which.

Comment: You should not output a and b separately to shuffle the way you show.

Comment: ok will try ,thank you.But why is m<=sizeofarray wrong

Comment: Array indices are 0 .. size -1 so a for loop condition for that will be < size because array[size] is one past the end of the array.

Comment: @NaodTadele You read into your array `sizeofarray` numbers, which means you can only read indices from `0` to `sizeofarray - 1` and the rest of array values is unititiazlized (i.e. random numbers). And better make sure user never enters `sizeofarray` bigger than `25`.

Comment: your right, thanks

Comment: that makes sense

Comment: Re: "always moving the middle card to the front" -- FWIW, that's an **in shuffle**, because the top card goes into the deck. When the top card stays on top it's an **out shuffle**. Both are perfect shuffles. If I remember correctly, 8 perfect out shuffles will restore a 52-card deck to its original order, but it takes 52 in shuffles to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging reasons, you should separe the process of writing a user input and writing the algorithm itself. Because testing with testcases written in the code can save you a lot of time.

I would write the shuffle algorithm like this : (edit)

```cpp
  for(int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
    shuffledArray[i*2+1] = arr[i];
    shuffledArray[i*2] = arr[i+half];
  }
```

This example assumes that your output (shuffled) array is called shuffleArray, the input array called arr, and that you have an integer variable called size.

It will work only with binary shuffle. If you want to shuffle by 3 or 4, it may be a bit different.

Comment: really ,i cant seem to find the problem

Comment: Yes indexes were reversed. It's ok now.

Comment: Did you understand how ?
since i will iterate from 0 to 4, i*2 will be 0,2,4,6,8
And i*2+1 will be 1,3,5,7,9
We have our indexes like that. Just need to pick the right value for each then.